# Angularjs ng-disabled gets disabled if value is greater than 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have some values coming from json. if my values are 0, the click is working fine. but if the values from json are greater than 0, the button is getting disabled and not working initially. i am trying to do like and dislike options using this code. so that user can select like button" one time or "dislike button" one time.any solution for this?

```
     //html
     <button class="label" ng-disabled="tvshow.episode.ratings.loved" ng-init="tvshow.episode.ratings.loved"  ng-click="likeme(tvshow.episode)" >
                                    <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> 
{{tvshow.episode.ratings.loved}}</button>

                                <button class="label" ng-disabled="tvshow.episode.ratings.hated" ng-init="tvshow.episode.ratings.hated" ng-click="dislike(tvshow.episode)" >
                                    <i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i>
 {{tvshow.episode.ratings.hated}}</button>
```

---

```
//added click event for like and dislike buttons in js
                        $scope.likeme = function(episod){
                            episod.ratings.loved = parseInt(episod.ratings.loved) + 1;
                            if (parseInt(episod.ratings.hated) > 0)
                                episod.ratings.hated = parseInt(episod.ratings.hated) - 1;
                            episod.liked = true;
                            episod.disliked = false;
                        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have all the controller functionality you need.

Just change your markup to:

```
<button class="label" ng-disabled="tvshow.episode.liked" ng-click="likeme(tvshow.episode)">
    <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> 
    {{tvshow.episode.ratings.loved}}
</button>
<button class="label" ng-disabled="tvshow.episode.disliked" ng-click="dislike(tvshow.episode)">
    <i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i>
    {{tvshow.episode.ratings.hated}}
</button>
```

Note that I got rid of the `ng-init`s that didn't do anything, and just disabled each button if it had already been clicked.